# How to expand only leaf nodes with property red_color = true of jtree

Tags: java

I have a jtree with green leaf nodes and reds leaf nodes by implementing a custom CellRenderer.

i am doing this to expand the entire jtree:

```
expAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jTree1.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        jTree1.expandRow(i);
                    }
                }
            });
```

but How to create a action to programatically expand my jtree to only leaf nodes that have Red cells?

Comment: What determines whether a leaf is red or green?

Comment: @Abra: in the getTreeCellRendererComponent() i just set a boolean to say is the leaf should be red or green with setForeground(Color.GREEN); or red:

boolean failed = ((LeafNodeObject) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject()).isFailed();

  if (leaf && failed) {
   setForeground(Color.GREEN);
  }
  if (leaf && !failed) {
   setForeground(Color.RED);
  }

Comment: `if (jTree1.getPathForRow(i).getLastPathComponent().isRed()) jTree1.expandRow(i)`

Comment: ok so what to put in the isRed() method to get the TreeCell Component to be able to check wether it is red or green??

Comment: `getUserObject()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks here is the final code:

```
expFail.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Exand the root node 
    jTree1.expandRow(0);        
    //Getting the jtree row from the root containing my red and green leaf node
    DefaultMutableTreeNode dirNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jTree1.getPathForRow(2).getLastPathComponent();
    Enumeration enumDir = dirNode.preorderEnumeration();
    while (enumDir.hasMoreElements()) {
        //Walking through all nodes of dirNode
        DefaultMutableTreeNode enumDirNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) enumDir.nextElement();
        //If node is leaf and is red (returned by isFailed()) expand to the previous node of this leaf node
        if (enumDirNode.isLeaf() && !((LeafNodeObject) enumDirNode.getUserObject()).isFailed()) {
            jTree1.expandPath(new javax.swing.tree.TreePath(enumDirNode.getPreviousNode().getPath()));
        }
    }
}
```

});